# Dynamically update navbar cart amount

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a webshop using React, Typescript, React-bootstrap and a self-made API. In the Navbar, I want to dynamically show the number of products in the user's cart (showing Cart(2) if 2 products are in the cart). Right now, I'm using a useEffect to fetch the number of products in the cart from my API, but of course the useEffect only triggers when the page is re-rendered - which means that when I add or remove a product, it is not reflected in the Cart(?) number.

My Navbar is one (functional) component, where as my product selections are also separate functional components

How do I achieve that the number in my navbar Cart(?) updates when ever a product is added to the cart.

Below is the whole code from the Navbar.

Thanks in advance!

```
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";
import "../css/stylesheet.css";
import Logo from "../images/dinosaur-silhouette-white-small.png";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function NavBar() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0)


  const getProducts = async () => {
    let counter: number = 0
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3005/velocishop/customers/" + localStorage.uuid + "/baskets/" + localStorage.uuid + "/products")
    let products = await response.json()
    products.map((product: any) => {
      counter ++
    })
    setCounter(counter)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top">
        <a href="/" className="logo-img">
            <img src={Logo} alt="Logo"></img>
        </a>
      <Navbar.Brand className="nav-brand-txt" href="/">Velocishop</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/velocishop/register">Register</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        <Nav className="mr-sm-2">
        <NavDropdown title="Shop" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/products">All Dinosaurs</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Header>Size</NavDropdown.Header>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/size/Small/products">Small Dinosaurs</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/size/Medium/products">Medium Dinosaurs</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/size/Large/products">Large Dinosaurs</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Header>Diet</NavDropdown.Header>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/diet/Carnivore/products">Carnivores</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/diet/Herbivore/products">Herbivores</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/velocishop/diet/Omnivore/products">Omnivores</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
        <Nav.Link href="/velocishop/cart">Cart({counter})</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make useEffect rerender when counter changes by adding a dependency to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getProducts()
}, [counter])
```

Comment: Im not sure if this will work because count is only being affected from the use effect in the first place, he probably wants the state of the products in the dependency

Comment: Good point.  I just wanted him to be aware he could trigger rerenders.  He probably doesn't even want to make another request every time, so my guess is he will be rethinking the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to have the products in some type of global state (redux), then you can add that state to the [] at the end of the useEffect, so that it can rerender and update the count. Also instead of incrementing count why not just set the count to the length of the array ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use global state(redux or context) to trigger the useEffect, or pass the props which related the cart to the component

```
useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  }, [globalstate or prop])
```

when gloabalstate is changed useEffect will trigger again